# Excessive TempDB Usage When Using Pivot + Temp Tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2019, disk-space, tempdb

I have a stored procedure that is acting quite strangely, it basically works in this way:

```
--Populate #tmpActualsVertical with data(in this example 84,652,788 rows)

SELECT PlanningOperationalDataActualID
    ,ISNULL([Column1], '') [Column1]
    ,ISNULL([Column2], '') [Column2]
    ,--etc...
INTO #tmpActualsWithTransactionAttributes
FROM #tmpActualsVertical PivotQuery
PIVOT(MAX([Value]) FOR PlanningOperationalDataActualTransactionAttributeName IN (
            [Column1]
            ,[Column2]
    )) AS PivotValues;

--Should result in approx. 7,054,399 records Column1 and etc should be a NVARCHAR(255)
```

This generates the following query plan:

[image]

Individual Query Into Physical Table in production
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJT8H9fuF

Run in Development into temp table:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1arF3f_t

Run in Production into temp table:
(Actual query plan cannot be captured because the run fails)

When I run this in a production environment my SQL Server instance consumes all of the 250GB temp table while inserting into #tmpActualsWithTransactionAttributes and fails with a:

> Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of
> insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary
> space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to
> the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
> filegroup.

When I bring it onto a development environment and run it(with a larger tempDB file), it runs without issue and doesn't even seem to take up more than a few GB's of temp drive space.

If I change the query to put all records into a physical table(in development) I see:

[image]
[image]

This shows the total record set isn't even taking more than 10GB.

There must be some detail of the way SQL Server is storing these records that's causing it to fill up on the production server, but don't understand why it's doing that or how to address it. Does anyone know why the pivot operation would result in such a large TempDB utilization and how to address the issue without having to resort to physical tables?

Comment: Could you upload the execution plans from both your Prod & Dev environments to [Paste The Plan](http://pastetheplan.com), then [edit] your question to include the links to the plans? The details in the plan XML will give answerers much more info than is available in a screenshot of an execution plan.

Comment: Check your prod query plan, perhaps it is serial, so the query gets smaller memory grant. Looking at your plan picture we could see the cardinality estimate is fairly inaccurate. If a query gets not enough memory, processing will be partly done in tempdb. Additionly, don't you have other tempdb consumming queries on your production environment?

Comment: At a guess, poor or non-existent statistics on `PlanningOperationalDataActualID` is causing a poor distinct-value estimation. We really need these query plans

Comment: @Amtwo ok I added a production versions of a plan where I insert into physical tables, this was also taking a large portion of tempDB but isn't fully representative of what is going on in prod, I'll run these today and attach the two additional query plans when I have them.